# Does the Stack Overflow review-queue hard-limit need to be increased?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

**Disclaimer:**  I'm not yet a Stack Overflow reviewer, but I'd like to help out and I'm getting there.

Just now I saw in the [close votes review queue stats](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats) that at least 6 users had slammed up against the 40-vote review limit, and others had 30+, but there are still a huge amount of tasks (more than 4700) to be reviewed.

It's likely to stay that way, given the sheer size of SO, but having a lower limit would help, as would more reviewers.

Does the limit need to be doubled (again)?  I would suggest lowering the reputation requirement, but reputation says a lot, e.g. knowledge about site workings.

Comment: 40 close vote reviews is already hard work, I doubt that many people would be prepared to do more.

Comment: Historically 4700 is not a large number in the queue

Comment: @greg-449 Yeah, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406531/does-the-stack-overflow-review-queue-hard-limit-need-to-be-increased?noredirect=1#comment835145_406532... also, congrats on nearly reaching six digits in that area.

Comment: But if you double it then it'll just stabilise at 9700 instead...

Comment: I have a hard time paying attention with just 40.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, what we need is more reviewers, not a higher review limit.

It is much easier than you realize to slip into inattentiveness when doing reviews, especially when the queue is crammed with junk. That's why the review audits are there; they teach people that the rule when reviewing is "Pay Attention!".

Comment: You're absolutely right.  I guess it wouldn't really be fair to load all those votes onto just the top 5 or so; spreading it around is better.  Thanks; meanwhile, I'll work on reaching those four digits.

Comment: Counter-proposal: while that'd be good, what we also need is to [reduce the number of tasks that *have to be reviewed in the first place*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285903). While having hundreds of off-topic questions being posted every day can indeed be solved by (lots and lots) of more reviewers to close them, there are much better approaches.

Comment: @CertainPerformance: You're bucking human nature. Hard work and self-motivation are learned traits. The majority of humans avoid them as much as they can get away with.

Comment: as you get your vote too often desmissed and banned, you will never find enough people to review